# function to return an array with values in reverse alphabetical order

Tags: php

```
$foods = array(
 'meat' => array('burgers', 'steak', 'sausages', 'liver'),
 'cake' => array('victorian', 'chocolate', 'fruit', 'fudge')
 );
```

I want just the meat values in reverse alphabetical order and the function should return an array.

and I don't want the liver to be included in the array.

How can I do that?

I have done this but for some reasons I didn't like it. Looks very simple to me. can any one please suggest me a better way of doing that.
This is how I did it.

```
    function items($arr){

$x = $arr['meat'];
sort($x);
$z = array_reverse($x);
foreach ($z as $v){
 if($v == 'liver')continue;
   $r[] = $v ;   
}
return $r;

}

$foods = array(
'meat' => array('burgers', 'steak', 'sausages', 'liver'),
'cake' => array('viian', 'chocolate', 'fruit', 'fudge')
);

$x = items($foods);
var_dump($x);

?>
```

Comment: Don't like liver? Its' delicious!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you had a look at all the [available array sorting functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) and tried any of them?

Comment: Did you try to read array_reverse's manual page by chance?

Comment: I have inserted my own solution as well. please check

Comment: Why down votingggggg to my awesome question full of meat.

Comment: `if (($key = array_search('liver', $x)) !== false) unset $x[$key];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [rsort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php):

```
$meats = $foods['meat'];
rsort($meats);
if ($key = array_search('liver', $meats)) 
     unset($meats[$key]);
```

Comment: where does it says it gonna sort in alphabetical order? from lower to higher I can understand the numerical indexing sorting?

Comment: The example in the doc is sorted in reverse alphabetical order, it's the common use case for this function. From the doc: "The fruits have been sorted in reverse alphabetical order."

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, sort array:

```
sort($input)
```

This should do it:

```
$reversed = array_reverse($input);
```

And remove some:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($reversed);$i++) {
    if($reversed[$i] == "liver")
       unset($reversed[$i]);        
}
```

Comment: same as my solution. your are using for and I used foreach.

Comment: You updated your answer some minutes ago. Before i wrote this.